# Auto-clicking a button if text is found in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, greasemonkey

I'm trying to auto-click a button, but only if the word Submit is found on the page. Where I'm at right now:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var LookFor = "Submit";

    if($('body:contains("' + LookFor + '")').length > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('accept-button').click();
    }
});
```

I'm able to get it to alert me properly when I replace `document.getElementById('accept-button').click();` with `alert("Found: " + LookFor);`, and `document.getElementById('accept-button').click();` works correctly on its own, independent of the rest of the code, so I feel like I'm on the right track, but rather than just alerting me, I want it to automatically click this button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, you're saying if you comment out the `if` block and just had the click line, the click works?

Comment: @Taplar Yeah, that's what's got me so confused. I'm pretty new to this, just trying to cobble together a userscript to replace a broken chrome extension I used to use, so I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, just don't know what.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, right before where you have your `if`, try putting this: `console.log(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('Submit'));`

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: What did it log?

Comment: Oh, I see, I have an error message: ERROR: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! Cannot read property 'click' of null
eval @ VM34899 userscript.html:2

Answer (score -1):

Instead of looking for any word anywhere, put it e.g. as a data attribute to the body

html:

```
<body data-custom-action="Submit">...</body>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
  if ($('body').data('custom-action') === 'Submit') {
    $('#accept-button').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: He's making an userscript, so he probably cannot alter what HTML he receives from the server.